# scrollbars of a CScrollView in a CDockablePane are disabled

Tags: mfc, scrollbar, dockable-windows, ccscrollview

I've designed a toolbox control. It's inside a CDockablePane object. Since the tools inside it may need to be scrolled, I've created a CScrollView as a child of the pane and have inserted the tools inside it as children. Based on the pane size, scrollbars of the CScrollView object appear properly, but clicking on them doesn't scroll the view. It seems that they're disabled. When I use SS_NOTIFY style when creating the CScrollView, the CScrollView object receives mouse clicks, but when i don't use the style, it doesn't. But it seems that the scroll bars inside the view control don't receive clicks. When mouse hover over them, no visual effect in scroll bars appears. It seems that the scroll bars are disabled, while I've not created nor manipulate them.
What's wrong?
mouse wheel works. click on scrollbars is received by the scroll view, not by the scrollbars. inside handler, i wrote this code:

```
CScrollBar *pScroll = GetScrollBarCtrl(SB_VERT);
if (pScroll->GetSafeHwnd())
{
    ...
```

if is not true. this means that the scroll view has not a scroll bar, but if so, how is it shown?!
any idea?
...
since i didn't get answer, i'm going to clarify my question with a sample code:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4829119/930501%20-%20t3.zip
in this sample, how can i scroll my view as i do with other views like class view and file view?
the sample code screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pu5chpyj9hqeal/Screenshot%202014-07-23%2003.40.26.png

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize by calling SetScrollSizes? The scroll bars are enabled only when the sizeTotal is larger than the view window size.

Comment: yes, i did. indeed the scrollbars appear properly with proper thumb sizes. but they appear disabled.